# django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-database

I have a problem with Django migrations on empty DB. When I want to migrate I have a circular dependency error. Circular dependency error between two apps that related by foreign keys

/firstapp/models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
   ...


class Doctor(Person):
    hospital = models.ForeignKey('hospital.Hospital', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None,blank = True)
    ...

class Patient(Person):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None)
```

/secondapp/models.py

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    ...
    main_doctor = models.ForeignKey('authoriz.Doctor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,verbose_name="Main Doctor")
    calendar = models.ForeignKey('schedule.Calendar',verbose_name="calendar",null = True)
    ...

class Seat(models.Model):
    hospital = models.ForeignKey('Hospital', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

After

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 136, in handle
    plan = executor.migration_plan(targets)
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 60, in migration_plan
    for migration in self.loader.graph.forwards_plan(target):
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 280, in forwards_plan
    self.ensure_not_cyclic(target, lambda x: (parent.key for parent in self.node_map[x].parents))
  File "/home/user/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 370, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: authoriz.0001_initial, hospital.0001_initial
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Temporarily comment out foreign keys to break the circular dependency. It looks like you could do this by commenting out `Hospital.doctor`. Remove the existing migrations and run `makemigrations` to recreate them.

Finally, uncomment the foreign keys, and run `makemigrations` again. You should end up with migrations without any circular dependencies.

Comment: I have the same issue but, in my case, I don't get the name of the models in circular dependency, I just get the names of the apps. How can I know which models are circularly dependent?

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto the error message here didn't name the models either, I had to look at the foreign keys between apps. We can't help you in the comments here, because we don't know your models.

Comment: There must be a better way, right? Why is there not another solution other than commenting and uncommenting.

Comment: @NickSmith this question is several years old, uses made-up variables like `firstapp`, and doesn't include the migrations that were failing, so it's not the best place to try to solve your problem. When I created two apps with fks to each other in Django 3.1, it created two migrations for one of the apps and avoided a circular dependency in the migrations, so no commenting-out was necessary.

Comment: @Alasdair Cool to see a response!! I am still getting the err, can I post a new question with my details and paste the link here?

Comment: @NickSmith No promises I'll be able to help, but if you post a new question I'll have a look.

Comment: @Alasdair Would love your help... question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332466/circulardependencyerror-on-foreign-keys-pointing-to-each-other-django THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Should be useful if you add your Calendar model. However don't use the inheritance without abstract modal.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, it will be usefull for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Like you might have defined them as something below:

```
new_field = models.ForeignKey(ForeignModel, ...)
```

Instead do this:

```
new_field = models.ForeignKey("ForeignModel", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your existing virtual environment and create a new one.
2. In your models files, comment out all `ForeignKey` fields.
3. Run migrations and migrate
4. Uncomment the `ForeignKey` fields you commented
5. Again run migrations and migrate