# CircularDependencyError on Foreign Keys Pointing to Each Other Django

Tags: django, django-models

I get a [circular dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705237/django-db-migrations-exceptions-circulardependencyerror) that makes me have to comment out a field. Here is how my models are set up:

```
class Intake(models.Model):
    # This field causes a bug on makemigrations. It must be commented when first
    # running makemigrations and migrate. Then, uncommented and run makemigrations and
    # migrate again.
    start_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        "widgets.Widget",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="start_widget",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

class Widget(PolymorphicModel):
    intake = models.ForeignKey(Intake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

By the way, Widget's PolymorphicModel superclass is from [here](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Why is this happening and how can I solve it **without having to comment out over and over again**? Thanks!

EDIT: THE FULL ERR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in build_graph
    self.graph.ensure_not_cyclic()
  File "/Users/nicksmith/Desktop/proj/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 274, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: intakes.0001_initial, widgets.0001_initial
```

Comment: Have you tried it with Widget's intake FK to-value as an string? Thus "your_app_label.Intake"

Comment: why do you use ```"widgets.Widget"``` rather than ```"Widget"```?

Comment: @Blackeagle52 Do you mean to write `models.ForeignKey("intakes.Intake"...` instead of doing `models.ForeignKey(Intake...`

Comment: @ha-neul The reason for this is because these models are in different files, so if I were to import eachother, then I will get a circular import error.

Comment: I don't get that error with your models and the latest versions `Django==3.1.4` and `django-polymorphic==3.0.0`. When I run `makemigrations` Django creates three migrations `intake/migrations/0001_initial.py` (Create model Intake), `intake/migrations/0002_intake_start_widget.py` (Add field start_widget to intake), and `widgets/migrations/0001_initial.py` (Create model Widget).

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by your comment *having to comment out over and over again*. Even if you do get the circular dependency error you should only have to comment/uncomment once to create the initial migrations.

Comment: @Alasdair is there any way for you to share your code that you're doing right now in an answer? By commenting and unncommenting over and over I just meant whenever someone else needs to get set up. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You would normally store the migrations in your version control system, so other users wouldn't have to run `makemigrations` to create the initial migrations.

Comment: There isn't really any code to share - I created a new project with two apps `intake` and `widgets`, and added the models to the `models.py`. The only change I had to make was to add imports for `PolymorphicModel` and `Intake`.

Answer (score 2):

```
     line 274, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: POS.0001_initial, CRM.0001_initial, CRM.0002_remove_divisions_cc
```

This type of errors that i approach for every fresh setup, the solution is quite simple:

1. Delete all migrations.
2. find all your "models.ForeignKey" in the project, replace them with:

   models.CharField(('Disabled for Dependency issue'), max_length=20, blank=True) # models.ForeignKey

*Exclude environment directory.

3. run makemigrations

   python manage.py makemigrations
4. get back your foreignkeys, replace all the following with blank

   models.CharField(('Disabled for Dependency issue'), max_length=20, blank=True) #
5. run makemigrations again

   python manage.py makemigrations
   python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1):

In Django doc [about foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:

Here is an example from the doc:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # ...

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass
```

So, in your case, this might work:

```
# put both models in the same models.py

class Intake(models.Model):

    start_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        "Widget",                      # use "Widget" the name of the model
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="start_widget",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

class Widget(PolymorphicModel):
    intake = models.ForeignKey(Intake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or

```
class Widget(PolymorphicModel):
    intake = models.ForeignKey("Intake", on_delete=models.CASCADE) #use "Intake" rather than Intake.

class Intake(models.Model):

    start_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        Widget,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="start_widget",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

**If you have to have two models in different models.py**, then use name of models in both cases.

```
# they are in separate models.py

##### in this case, do not import models from the other app.

class Widget(PolymorphicModel):
    intake = models.ForeignKey("myapp.Intake", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
#use "myapp.Intake" rather than Intake.


# in different models.py

# use "widgets.Widget" rather than Widget

class Intake(models.Model):

    start_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        "widgets.Widget",           
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="start_widget",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Or import model from one app, but use "myapp.MyModel" in the other app.

```
# in this models.py,  do not import Widget model


class Intake(models.Model):
    start_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        "widgets.Widget",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="start_widget",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


#### in another models. py

from myapp.models import Intake             # import model

class Widget(PolymorphicModel):
    intake = models.ForeignKey(Intake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I tried this (specifically "If you have to have two models in different models.py, then use name of models in both cases") but still didn't work :(. Let me know if I can provide any more info. Thanks for your time and help!!

Comment: That is odd, it works well in my case. In fact, in two models.py, one with "widgets.Widget" and the other ```Intake``` works too. I updated my answer with another way to do it. The only thing I did not try is to use ```PolymorphicModel```. But by using ```models.Model``` both ways work fine. So, if you are using string presentation, you should not import model from another app's models.py.

Comment: Did you delete migration files and try again?

Comment: Let me give it another shot and get back to you

Comment: Maybe you can paste full trace back.

Comment: It didnt work unfortunately.. I added the full error

Answer (score 0):

I'd just had a very similar `CircularDependencyError` with Django 4.2.6.
My goal was to just get all our Django tests working in CI (after upgrading from an older Django) while rebuilding the DB every time like this:
`rm -f data.sqlite.db && manage.py migrate && manage.py test`.

Neither passing a string as first argument to each `ForeignKey` instead of a class, nor replacing (one, or the other, or both) the `ForeignKey`'s with dummy `CharField` - none of that was resolving the error and I got pretty frustrated.

What ended up working was running `manage.py makemigrations app1 app2` (with **both apps simultaneously**, instead of one by one).
As a result, Django generated not 1 but 2 migrations for one of the apps, and allowed me to run `manage.py migrate` without `CircularDependencyError`.

To be precise, I kept passing string as first argument to `ForeignKey`, which might be necessary, but was definitely not sufficient in my case to resolve the error.

I think `makemigrations` without parameters is supposed to go through the `INSTALLED_APPS` and detect all missing migrations automatically, but it kept saying `No changes detected` so I had to specify the apps myself, and made the mistake of doing it one by one.